# bash or awk - generating report from complex data set

Tags: awk

I have a program that generates a large data file, and I put a small sample in the input section. What I am trying to do is start with an AOUT. Then look at the 4th column to find its next connection, which shows up in the second column somewhere else in the file and repeat those steps until it ends with an AIN in the first column. The number of connections between the AOUT and AIN varies from just one to over ten. If there isn't an AIN at the end, there shouldn't be any output. the output should start with AOUT and show each connection until it reaches AIN. Is there a way to use awk or anything to create my desired output?

input (this is a small section there are many more and the order they appear is not standard)

```
AOUT,03xx:LY0372A,LIC0372.OUT,LIC0372
PIDA,03xx:LIC0372,LT372_SEL.OUT,LT372_SEL
SIGSEL,03xx:LT372_SEL,LT1_0372.PNT,LT1_0372
AIN,03xx:LT1_0372
```

output:

```
03xx:LY0372A                
   =03xx:LT372_SEL.OUT         
   =03xx:LT1_0372.PNT         
   =03xx:LT1_0372
```

output format:

```
(AOUT)
  =(any number of jumps)
  =(any number of jumps))
  =(AIN)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is your data and what you want. You need to better explain it. Do you always have a sequence of 4 lines? The fist one estarts with AOUT, the second with PIDA, the third with SIGSEL and the fouth with AIN? What do you mean by "any # next step"?

Comment: What did you try up to now? Please post your attempts to code it with awk.

Comment: Is the string before `:` in some fields is always `03xx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't provide more input and answers to the questions in the comments above, a possible solution in AWK could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F',' '{
  if ($1 == "AOUT") {
    output = $2 "\n"
    connector = $4
    sub (":.*", "", $2)
    label = $2
  }
  else if ($1 == "AIN") {
    output = output "   =" $2
    print output
    output = ""
  } 
  else if (output != "") {
    if ($2 == label ":" connector) {
      output = output "   =" label ":" $3 "\n"
      connector = $4
    }
  }
}' input.csv
```